# View PDF document in Rich Text Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, rich-text-editor, sitecore-mvc

I am currently trying something new and have a query to make. have tried browsing through the net for a solution but is not displaying what I would like to achieve.

The following is what I would need to achieve

***To accomplish:***

1. to create a PDF document within the PDF contatiner in the rich text editor within Sitecore
2. Users can view the PDF document instead of having to click on a link to download.

***What I have searched and gotten from the net so far:***

1. Uploading the PDF as a link for users to download.

***System:***
1. am currently trying on Sitecore 8.2

Hence, could someone point me in the right direction that i can reference to for the creation of PDF document within the rich text editor

Comment: Not sure what the `PDG conatainer` in... what are are you trying to do, link to a PDF in the Media Library and have it open in the browser rather than asking the user to download/save it?

Comment: @jammykam - I am not trying to save the PDF file within the media library but to display the PDF document in the rich text editor with additional input text or images. Hence, there is no need for the user to download or to open in the new browser.

Comment: I assume you are [trying to do something like this](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20170921/14153038261/backpages-biggest-law-enforcement-critic-doesnt-think-he-needs-sesta-to-take-down-backpage.shtml), embedding a PDF within the page? This is not possible OOTB with Sitecore, personally I am not not sure how to do it, maybe someone else does, but please clarify with examples to help other understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @jammykam - yes, that is what i am trying to achieve. To embed a PDF within the page in Sitecore 8.2. So to allow that is to have an OOTB module with rich text editor in Sitecore?